# How to match precisely an expression finishing with 0 and another finishing with 0 followed by a number with grep?

Tags: r, regex, nested-lists

I have made a simulation in R with 125 scenarios, each simulated 100 times.
The scenarios are identified by fraction numbers, such as "075_05_0", "025_025_025", "0_05_1", where the results of each simulation is stored in a data frame.

I would now like to put these scenario-specific data frames in a nested list, where the first level of the list relates to the scenario, and the next level stores the 100 data frames of the given scenario.

I  tried to use the following code:

```
reslist  <- list()

for(i in seq_along(scenarios){
 reslist[[i]] <- mget(ls(pattern =  scenarios[i]))

}
```

where "scenarios" is a character vector containing the names of all the 125 scenarios.

This code works fine, except when the ending number of my string is 0 (e.g., 075_025_0). Whenever this is the case, the second level of my nested list includes also the data frames of all scenarios whose ending number starts with a 0 followed by a number (for example: 075_025_025, 075_025_05, 075_025_075).

I then tried to replace my code by using explicitly the "^" and "$" to match the start and end of my string, respectively, as follows:

```
reslist  <- list()

for(i in seq_along(scenarios){
 reslist[[i]] <- mget(ls(pattern =  grep("^",scenarios[i],"$",value=T)))

}
```

However, this leads to the same problem.
I need to assure that simulations from a scenario such as 075_025_025 (alternatively 075_025_05, 075_025_075) are stored in a separate list from the list of the scenario finishing with a 0 not followed by any other number (i.e., 075_025_0)

Is there any regular expression to match precisely a scenario finishing with 0 and another matching scenarios finishing with 0 followed by a number (_025, _05, _075)?

If you can recommend better way to approach my problem, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a thought: The issue goes back to the simulation. Why not put everything in a list during simulation instead of putting them in your working/global environment?

Also could you include the 10 elements of the `scenario` string and explain at least 2 or 3 of them on what you expect

Comment: That could have been a clever solution if my results wouldn't be that large. I had to set-up my simulation framework in such way that the results are automatically stored in specific folders - I cannot store them all in my working environment.  

What I do now/here is loading a bunch of results related to a given input that I indicate at the start of another script which aims to analyze these results. I know this is probably not the cleverest way to do it, but that's what I've came up a year ago when I built the simulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `grep` outside the `ls`.  Here, we read the question as the match the last chunk of numbers that starts with 0.  The pattern used will be match the `_` followed by 0 and one or more digits (`\\d+`) at the end (`$` of the string

```
reslist <- list()
for(i in seq_along(scenarios) {
      reslist[[i]] <- mget(grep("_0\\d+$", 
                 ls(pattern = scenarios[i]), value = TRUE))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @akrun. I'm afraid, however, that this doesn't solve my issue neither, unfortunately. I keeps pulling data frames from scenarios such as 075_025_025, 075_025_05, 075_025_075 in my list of scenario 075_025_0. I need to find a way that assures that data frames from scenarios ending with *_025, *_05, *_075 go each within their own scenario-specific lists.

Comment: @Marie-ChristineRufener In that case why not do a split i.e. `split(yourvec, sub("_[^_]+$", "", yourvec))`

Comment: thanks for your clever solution. Didn't think on splitting my vector! That one worked perfectly fine :)